# Mandrill SMTP error when I hosted my website

Tags: php, email, yii, smtp, mandrill

I have used Mandrill for SMTP and the below code is well worked for me in localhost. But the same code did not work, when I hosted my website in remote.

It displays an error

> Smtp->error password not accepted from server 535. Incorrect authenticate data.

This is my code. Please do help me.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Contacts;
    if(isset($_POST['Contacts']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Contacts'];
                      Yii::import('application.extensions.phpmailer.JPhpMailer');
                    $mail = new JPhpMailer;
                    $mail->IsSMTP();
                    $mail->Host = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';
                    $mail->Port ='587';
                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                    $mail->SMTPSecure="tls";
                    $mail->Username = 'xxx@gmail.com';
                    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
                    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive =true;
                    $mail->Password = 'tshb-mA19EdIvdQf2mO8KA';
                    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['Contacts']['email'], $_POST['Contacts']['email']);
                    $mail->Subject = 'New Mail Receiverd';
                    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
                   $mail->MsgHTML("DASDSAD");
                       $msgBody="<div><ul>";
                        foreach($model->attributes as $key=>$value)
                        {
                             $msgBody.="<li>".$key." - ".$value."</li>";      
                        }
                        $msgBody.="</ul></div>";
                   $mail->MsgHTML($msgBody);
                    $mail->AddAddress('xxx@gmail.com', 'xxx');
                    $ret=$mail->Send();


        if($model->save())
                        print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"; 
                        print "alert('Thank you for contacting us.')"; 
                        print "</script>";  
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: please do not post duplicate of the same question

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason you'll see this is if you're using a shared hosting provider that is redirecting SMTP connections, or doesn't allow external SMTP connections.

So instead of connecting to smtp.mandrillapp.com, you may be connecting to the local mail server which doesn't recognize your Mandrill credentials.  We have some [common troubleshooting steps in our KB here](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/24633717-Why-am-I-getting-a-Relay-Access-Denied-error-trying-to-send-through-SMTP-) that we recommend working through to ensure you're connecting as expected.

If you're still seeing issues, you can also get in touch with support directly by clicking on the 'Support' button in the bottom left of your Mandrill account.